# How do I change resolution?

Tags: 12.04

I'm using 1024x768 but I want to change to 1280x800 resolution. This isn't detected by OS so I found if I put the following into /etc/X11/xorg.conf it could work but it didn't. How do I fix this? I tried to install some application from software center like arand but it didn't even started.

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Configured Video Device"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Default Screen"
        Monitor         "Configured Monitor"
        Device          "Configured Video Device"

        SubSection "Display"

          Modes "1280x800"

        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try xrandr: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr or a easier http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/set-your-screen-resolution-higher-than-you-should-with-newrez

Comment: I get this error: `Current display must be LVDS1` what does mean that?

Comment: try newrez, that means that your screen isn't LVDS1/ isn't the right name.